# Looping an output to a .txt file in Java

Tags: java, file-io, while-loop

So here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){

    ArrayList<Employee> ArrEmployee = new ArrayList<Employee>(); //  array for employee objects

        try {
            Scanner txtIn = new Scanner(new File("payroll.txt"));
            PrintWriter txtOut = new PrintWriter("payrollError.txt");


            while (txtIn.hasNext()) { // looping through the payroll.txt file and creating Employee objects from its data
                try{
                long EmployeeNumber = txtIn.nextLong();
                String EmployeeName = txtIn.next();
                String LastName = txtIn.next();
                double HoursWorked = txtIn.nextDouble();
                double HourlyWage = txtIn.nextDouble();
                if (HourlyWage > 10.35){ 
                    throw new InputMismatchException(); // throws exception if the hourly wage is less than 10.35$
                }
                else
                    ArrEmployee.add(new Employee(EmployeeNumber,EmployeeName,LastName,HoursWorked,HourlyWage)); // creates Employee objects according to the input payroll.txt
                }
                catch (InputMismatchException n) { // catching long,strings and doubles in the payroll.txt that aren't valid
                    txtOut.println(Employee.EmployeeNumber + " " + Employee.EmployeeName + " " + Employee.LastName + " " + Employee.HoursWorked + " " + Employee.HourlyWage);
                    System.out.println("lol");
                      }
                txtOut.close();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File payroll.txt was not found.");

            }

          }

        }
```

I'm trying to output to a .txt file called payrollError.txt but for some reason, the while loop goes on infinitely...

I can't seem to find the problem in my main class and any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code from the payroll.txt :

```
31718 PHILLIP LENNOX 55.0 20.00
11528 NANCY TROOPER 40.0 10.45
16783 JOHN CONNAUGHT 30.5 10.00
10538 PETER DUNCAN 45.0 10.75
21O15 JAMES HAROLD 32.0 10.50
61326 HARRY KUHN 25.0 12.30
82465 MICHELLE BENOIT 50.0 18.50
31816 DANIELLE RAYMOND 35.5 15.25
73745 JACK O'TOOLE 28.0 11.50
81514 VICTORIA HALL 48.5 17.50
71854 ALI MOHUMAD 35.0 10.75
92012 ALLAN MARS 36.0 15.00
52853 MICHAEL BOONE 60.5 17.50
41714 JULIE HART 25.0 10.50
58342 MIKE HEINZ 28.2 16.85
62080 PIETRO SULA 32.5 11.50
21638 MICHEL RAE 40.5 12.50
52726 MITCHELL HACKETT 23,7 12.05
```

Basically it's supposed to loop through these (long,string,string,double,double) like by line, find any values that are invalid like a double written as 23,7 instead of 23.7 and output it to my file payrollError.txt.

My Employee class:

```
public class Employee {

     public static long EmployeeNumber;
     public static String EmployeeName;
     public static String LastName;
     public static double HoursWorked;
     public static double HourlyWage;

    public Employee(long EmployeeNumber, String EmployeeName, String LastName, double HoursWorked, double HourlyWage ){

        this.EmployeeNumber = EmployeeNumber;
        this.EmployeeName = EmployeeName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.HoursWorked = HoursWorked;
        this.HourlyWage = HourlyWage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't close the output in your `while` loop body. Also, please follow Java variable naming conventions. Instead of displaying "lol" try and output the message you're writing. If you can't initialize the `Employee` it's hard to see how your existing method could get the values that were read. Finally, you need to `close()` your `PrintWriter` (or use a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) as below to do it for you). Something like

```
List<Employee> al = new ArrayList<>();
try (PrintWriter txtOut = new PrintWriter("payrollError.txt")) {
    Scanner txtIn = new Scanner(new File("payroll.txt"));
    while (txtIn.hasNext()) {
        long employeeNumber;
        String employeeName;
        String lastName;
        double hoursWorked;
        double hourlyWage;

        try {
            employeeNumber = txtIn.nextLong();
            employeeName = txtIn.next();
            lastName = txtIn.next();
            hoursWorked = txtIn.nextDouble();
            hourlyWage = txtIn.nextDouble();
            if (hourlyWage > 10.35) {
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            } else {
                al.add(new Employee(employeeNumber, employeeName,
                                lastName, hoursWorked, hourlyWage));
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException n) {
            String msg = employeeNumber + " " + employeeName + " "
                    + lastName + " " + hoursWorked + " " + hourlyWage;
            txtOut.println(msg);
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
        // txtOut.close(); // <-- this is inside the loop.
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File payroll.txt was not found.");
}
```

Your fields cannot be `static` in your `Employee` class! (And I would make them lowercase to follow Java naming conventions; otherwise they look like class names)

```
 private /* static */ long EmployeeNumber;
 private /* static */ String EmployeeName;
 private /* static */ String LastName;
 private /* static */ double HoursWorked;
 private /* static */ double HourlyWage;
```

Making the fields `private` is an example of encapsulation.

Comment: Sorry for the "lol"!! It's actually just for testing if the inputmismatchexception was working... Also I have a separate class Employee with constructor for the long,string,string,double,double do I need to redo it like you did in my main?

Comment: How can I answer that without seeing it?

Comment: Added the Employee class to the post!

Comment: @X1XX `static` means one. If those fields are static, then your instances have no independent values. They can't be static.

Comment: But if I don't make it static, my             `txtOut.println(Employee.EmployeeNumber + " " + Employee.EmployeeName + " " + Employee.LastName + " " + Employee.HoursWorked + " " + Employee.HourlyWage);`
line does not work for the output (Java recommended I change the variables to static)

Comment: My answer fixed that. You can't print there anyway, you failed to create the `Employee`.

Comment: I've tried using your code, but this happens: `31718 PHILLIP LENNOX 55.0 20.0
11528 NANCY TROOPER 40.0 10.45
10538 PETER DUNCAN 45.0 10.75
0 null null 0.0 0.0
0 null null 0.0 0.0` It prints out in the payroll.txt and the 0 null null 0.0 0.0 loops infinitely...

Comment: It actually is printing out all the names which aren't supposed to throw the inputmismatchexception up until there is an exception, then loops for the 0 null null 0.0 0.0

Comment: @X1XX Like I said in my answer which I've deleted. If one of the methods `nextLong()` or `nextDouble()` throws an `InputMismatchException` the next token in the `Scanner` won't be retrieved which means that `hasNext()` will forever return `true`

Comment: @Titus Any idea how I could fix that? I can't seem to figure out another to do this than with this while loop

Comment: @X1XX you need to consume the next token, just call `txtIn.next()` in the `catch` block

Comment: @Titus All it's doing now is writing in every 5th line of payroll.txt in the payrollError.txt with or without inputmismatchexception...

Comment: Elliott, got any input on this? You've been extremely helpful so far

Comment: I think you may find using a debugger very helpful, or at least adding debugging messages to your code. What do you think `if (hourlyWage > 10.35) {` is doing

Answer (score 0):

Better to use buffered reader and writer when using file streams .

modifying your code using those:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Employee> ArrEmployee = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        FileReader bfr = null;
        try {
            bfr = new FileReader(new File("payroll.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(bfr);
        String EmployeeName = "no data";
        FileWriter bfw = null;
        try {
            bfw = new FileWriter("payroolError.txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedWriter txtOut = new BufferedWriter(bfw);

    try {
        while (br.read() != -1) {
            String temp = br.readLine();
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(" ");
            String[] items = p.split(temp);
            try {
                int EmployeeNumber = Integer.parseInt(items[0]);
                EmployeeName = items[1];
                String LastName = items[2];
                double HoursWorked = Double.parseDouble(items[3]);
                double HourlyWage = Double.parseDouble(items[4]);
                if (HourlyWage > 10.35) {
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                } else {
                    ArrEmployee
                            .add(new Employee(EmployeeNumber, EmployeeName,
                                    LastName, HoursWorked, HourlyWage));
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException n) {
                txtOut.write(EmployeeName);
            } catch (InputMismatchException n) {
                txtOut.write(EmployeeName);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}}
```